# Определить зашел ли пользователь с браузера телевизора

Tags: javascript

Как можно определить зашел ли пользователи на с браузера телевизора?
Только по `user agent` ?

Comment: `Только по user agent ?` - а разве есть еще другие способы узнать кто зашел? Странный вопрос.

Comment: есть, пробуй зацепиться в стилях за @media tv {....}

Comment: @MaxWall, метки смотрим, причем тут `css-media`? Либо ТС сам не знает и не понимает, что хочет и что делает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно пробовать через @media - http://htmlbook.ru/css/media

```
@media tv {
   html {
      border-color: red; - здесь любе не влияющее на внешний вид свойство, которое потом можно чекнуть из js, есть оно или нет
   }
}
```

А через userAgent не поможет, там в телевизорах возможен целый зоопарк браузеров - https://udger.com/resources/ua-list/device-detail?device=Smart%20TV

Comment: Как можно провести отладку?

Comment: Ответ не соответствует меткам и в целом вопросу, чем поможет `media` для отладки и конечно же для сервера? Ничем, только если делать зоопарк форм и скрытых полей, потом отправлять через какие-то прокладки на сервер. Бред полнейший. Когда есть `user-agent`. `css-media` нужен для адаптации страниц, под разные устройства,  а на счет зоопарк браузеров, да хоть два зоопарка, какая разница, это все можно отрефакторить без проблем и сделать регулярку для отсева лишек. Не ну конечно, если ему нужна адаптация сие ради, то ТС - этого не написал в вопросе и не дал понять, что хочет сделать.